# How to adjust the position of errobar in stack bar plot by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
    ##data test_1
    ID  type    value
    cu  s   0.2814644
    cu  s   0.278847685
    cu  s   0.1909515
    cu  t   11.71781248
    cu  t   11.55618308
    cu  t   12.91048587
    Bu  b   12.70410914
    Bu  b   13.2930925
    Bu  b   14.43481323
```

##code

```
 ggplot(test_1, aes(ID,  value , fill = type)) +
           theme_bw() +
           stat_summary(
             geom = "col",
             fun = "mean",
             position = "stack",
             width = 0.6,
             col = "black",
             size = 1
           ) +
           stat_summary(
             geom = "errorbar",
             fun.min = function(x)
               mean(x) - sd(x),
             fun.max = function(x)
               mean(x) + sd(x),
             width = 0.1,
             size = 1
           )
```

[image]

The errobar and bar don't match,so I change the order of bar.

```
test_1$type <- factor(test_1$type, levels = c("b", "t", "s"))
```

[image]
#still don't match(the errobar of green bar is lower than it should be)! But I figure out the problam is the bar is stack but the errobar can't adujst automatically.

Comment: Put `position = "stack"` in the `stat_summary("errorbar")` call, just like you have it in the other one.

Comment: ggplot(test_1, aes(ID,  value , fill = type)) +
  theme_bw() +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "col",
    fun = "mean",
    position = "stack",
    width = 0.6,
    col = "black",
    size = 1
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "errorbar",
    fun.min = function(x)
      mean(x) - sd(x),
    fun.max = function(x)
      mean(x) + sd(x),
    position = "stack",
    width = 0.1,
    size = 1
  )
Warning messages:
1: Stacking not well defined when not anchored on the axis 
2: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (position_stack).  
##when i do this errobar is missing

Answer (score 0):

I found a stupid way to solve this question. To avoid the wrong position of errobar, I plot errobar twice.
##data

```
test_2
ID  type    value
cu  s   0.2814644
cu  s   0.278847685
cu  s   0.1909515
cu  t   
cu  t   
cu  t   
Bu  b   12.70410914
Bu  b   13.2930925
Bu  b   14.43481323

test_3
ID  type    value
Bu  s   
Bu  s   
Bu  b   
cu  t   11.71781248
cu  t   11.55618308
cu  t   12.91048587
```

##code

```
d1$type <- factor(d1$type, levels =c("b", "t", "s")) ggplot(d1, aes(ID,  value , fill = type)) +   theme_bw() +   stat_summary(
    geom = "col",
    fun = "mean",
    position = "stack",
    width = 0.6,
    col = "black",
    size = 1   ) +   stat_summary(
    data = d2,
    geom = "errorbar",
    fun.min = function(x)
      mean(x) - sd(x),
    fun.max = function(x)
      mean(x) + sd(x),
    position = "identity",
    width = 0.1,
    size = 1   ) +   stat_summary(
    data = d3,
    geom = "errorbar",
    fun.min = function(x)
      mean(x) - sd(x)+0.25,
    fun.max = function(x)
      mean(x) + sd(x)+0.25,
    position = "identity",
    width = 0.1,
    size = 1   )
```

[image]